# Yii - Dinamically change TbGridView options behavior based on other data

Tags: php, yii

I have a Yii 1 application and I want to change the behavior of TbGridView columns based on a 'status' column. If my status is 'Y' I want to call one URL on TbButtonColumn. If it's 'N', change the title and url of TbButtonColumn.
Is it possible?

My code:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
'id'=>'my-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'description',
    status, // <--- This here can be 'Y' or 'N'. Based on this column I want to change Options column behavior.
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{Do Something}',
        'buttons'=>array
        (
            'Do Something' => array
            (
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("myUrlForY", array("somedata"=>$data->somedata))',
            ),
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 20px'),
    ),
),
```

));

Comment: What do you mean option column? Are you referring to the `TbButtonColumn`?

Comment: Yes @topher, the TbButtonColumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass php expressions into the `url` property of `TbButtonColumn` and since `$data` refers to the current model you can access the `status` via `$data->status`:

```
'url' => '$data->status == "Y" ? 
     Yii::app()->createUrl("myUrlForY", array("somedata" => $data->somedata)) : 
     Yii::app()->createUrl("myUrlForN", array("somedata" => $data->somedata))',
```

Or even shorter if the url parameters are the same:

```
'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl(
    ($data->status == "Y" ? "myUrlForY" : "myUrlForN"),
    array("somedata" => $data->somedata)
)',
```

Or even shorter since if the expression passed into `url` is an array a url is created internally:

```
'url' => 'array(
    ($data->status == "Y" ? "myUrlForY" : "myUrlForN"),
    array("somedata" => $data->somedata)
)',
```